# Return type in method signature of ABI and contract differs - ethers.js call still works

Tags: ethers.js, abi, gnosis-safe, eip-1271

I observed a strange behaviour that I cannot explain.

I'm calling the EIP-1271 function

```
function isValidSignature(bytes32 _dataHash, bytes calldata _signature) external view returns (bytes4)
```

of the [Gnosis Safe Smart](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/da66b45ec87d2fb6da7dfd837b29eacdb9a604c5/contracts/handler/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.sol#L66) Contract. If the signature is valid, this method is expected to return the [EIP-1271](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271#motivation) magic value (`0x1626ba7e`).

I'm using ethers.js and this code:

```
import { Contract, utils, ethers } from "ethers";
...
const abi = ['function isValidSignature(bytes32 _message, bytes _signature) public view returns (bool)'];

const walletContract = new Contract("0xE1...", abi, provider);
let msg = "A simple message";
let sig = "0x";
const hashMessage = utils.hashMessage(msg);
const isValid = await walletContract.isValidSignature(hashMessage, sig);
if (!isValid ) {
   throw new Error("Invalid signature.");
}
```

The return types of the contract and the ABI differ: **byte4** vs. **bool**.
When I execute the code, `isValid` actually contains a boolean, whereas I would expect the call `await walletContract.isValidSignature(hashMessage, sig)` to fail because the return type is not byte4.

**How does that work? Does ethers.js do some implicit casting of byte4 to boolean?**

On a sidenote, using Web3j (Java), the same call fails with the following exception:
`org.web3j.tx.exceptions.ContractCallException: Unable to convert response`

Comment: Probably because it returns `bytes4(0)` which is then cast to a boolean as per the ABI?